# Is there a way to hold a collection of "messages" upto size 1 MB and write the result to JSON/CSV file

Tags: c#, system.reactive, blockingqueue

I have a blocking queue which keep getting messages through some app, now In asp.net app I tried to consume the queue and write the output into CSV/JSON file.

Here I want to hold messages up to 1MB which receive from blocking queue and then write it out, now again hold data for 1MB and write again...so on.

**In below code, I'm using `system.reactive` buffer and can hold number of observable 's and write to JSON, but Is there any way on size of observable 's?**

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly BlockingCollection<Message> MessagesBlockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<Message>();

    private static void Producer()
    {
        int ctr = 1;
        while (ctr <= 11)
        {
            MessagesBlockingCollection.Add(new Message { Id = ctr, Name = $"Name-{ctr}" });
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            ctr++;
        }
    }

    private static void Consumer()
    {
        var observable = MessagesBlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable().ToObservable();

        var bufferedNumberStream = observable.BufferWithThrottle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), 5)
                                    .Subscribe(ts =>
                                    {
                                        WriteToFile(ts.ToList());
                                    });
    }

    private static void WriteToFile(List<Message> listToWrite)
    {
        using (StreamWriter outFile = System.IO.File.CreateText(Path.Combine(@"C:\TEMP", $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")}.json")))
        {
            outFile.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listToWrite));
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Producer());
        var consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Consumer());
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Extension Reactive Method,

```
public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> BufferWithThrottle<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source,
                                                                            TimeSpan threshold, int noOfStream)
    {
        return Observable.Create<IList<TSource>>((obs) =>
        {
            return source.GroupByUntil(_ => true,
                                       g => g.Throttle(threshold).Select(_ => Unit.Default)
                                             .Merge(g.Buffer(noOfStream).Select(_ => Unit.Default)))
                         .SelectMany(i => i.ToList())
                         .Subscribe(obs);
        });
    }
```

Message Class,

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to buffer the data in Rx? If you must buffer the write, can you buffer using a [BufferedStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.bufferedstream?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: @Aron, I tried something using `'Rx Buffer`, but able to do with ONLY number of observable, not on size, please have a look this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104055/buffer-with-stream-size-instead-of-number-of-streams-reactive-extension-c-sharp

Comment: Question edited

Comment: I didn't say use Rx buffer. I said you use BufferedStream. You just wrap your FileStream with a BufferedStream. Message has no "size". Only the serialized form does...

Comment: Ok, meaning we can't determine observable message size? There is no `Rx` way?

Comment: I also reading this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53152134/buffer-by-time-or-running-sum-for-reactive-extensions

Comment: I mean that it is a meaningless question in .net (nothing to do with Rx). You are using managed memory. Alternatively there are 101 different answers to "message size".

Comment: @Enigmativity, please re-open this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104055/buffer-with-stream-size-instead-of-number-of-streams-reactive-extension-c-sharp, I will delete this one. Thanks!