# How to merge two observables with early completion

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

The behavior of the built-in [`Merge`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) operator is to complete when **both** sources are completed. I am searching for a variant of this operator that produces an observable that completes when **any** of the two source observables completes. For example if the first observable complete successfully and *later* the second observable complete with an exception, I want this exception to be ignored.

I came up with an implementation that concatenates a special sentinel exception to both enumerables, and then the merged sequence catches and suppresses this exception. I wonder if I am missing a simpler solution.

```
/// <summary>
/// Merges elements from two observable sequences into a single observable sequence,
/// that completes as soon as any of the source observable sequences completes.
/// </summary>
public static IObservable<T> MergeUntilAnyCompletes<T>(this IObservable<T> first,
    IObservable<T> second)
{
    var sentinel = new Exception();
    first = first.Concat(Observable.Throw<T>(sentinel));
    second = second.Concat(Observable.Throw<T>(sentinel));
    // Concat: Concatenates the second observable sequence to the first
    // observable sequence upon successful termination of the first.
    return first.Merge(second)
        .Catch(handler: (Exception ex) =>
        ex == sentinel ? Observable.Empty<T>() : Observable.Throw<T>(ex));
    // Catch: Continues an observable sequence that is terminated by an exception
    // of the specified type with the observable sequence produced by the handler.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fun hack:

```
public static IObservable<T> MergeUntilAnyCompletes<T>(this IObservable<T> first,
    IObservable<T> second)
{
    return Observable.Merge(
        first.Materialize(),
        second.Materialize()
    ).Dematerialize();
}
```

`Materialize` turns the observable into an observable of notifications, so `Merge` will no longer suppress the `OnCompleted` notification. When you `Dematerialize`, then that operator will see the `OnCompleted` and stops.

Side note: If you want some fun, slightly academic reading about `Materialize`/`Dematerialize` read [this blog post](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/12/29/more-linq-with-system-interactive-exploiting-the-code-data-relationship.aspx). He's writing about Ix, but the same thing applies to Rx.

Comment: That's a nice solution!

Comment: And the [blog post](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/12/29/more-linq-with-system-interactive-exploiting-the-code-data-relationship.aspx) was enlightening too! Although I can't find the Materialize/Dematerialize operators inside the [`System.Interactive`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/tree/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive/System/Linq/Operators) API.

Comment: Interesting. The post is 10 years old from one of the original devs on Rx and Ix, so not surprising that things have changed. But surprising that it is removed with no apparent equivalent.

Comment: 2021 update: `const shortMerge = (...sourceObservables) => merge(...sourceObservables.map((sourceObservable) => sourceObservable.pipe(materialize()))).pipe(dematerialize())`