# How to create an observable that signals the completion of two other observables?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive, rx.net

I have two `IObservable<T>`, and want to create a `IObservable<Unit>` (or some sort of `ISingle<Unit>`, if such a thing exists) that emits a completion signal when both complete, and nothing else. What's the idiomatic way to do this in Rx.NET?

I'm used to [Reactor Core](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/), in which case I'd use `flux1.then().and(flux2.then())`. But I don't believe Rx.NET offers the `then` and `and` operators.

Comment: What is the desirable behavior if one of the sequences fail before the other one has completed?

Comment: Ideally an error should be throw as soon as one fails.

Comment: In this case you may want to check out this question: [How to merge two observables with early completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59261017/how-to-merge-two-observables-with-early-completion)

Comment: Thank you @TheodorZoulias.

Comment: jackdry actually the built-in `Merge` operator has exactly the behavior that you want. As soon as one of the sequences fails, the merged sequence fails immediately too. And the other sequence, if it hasn't completed yet, is unsubscribed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both sequences are of the same type, you could use the `Merge` operator. It might be beneficial to throw the `IgnoreElements` in the mix, in order to reduce the synchronization stress associated with merging sequences that may contain huge number of elements.

```
IObservable<Unit> completion = sequence1.IgnoreElements()
    .Merge(sequence2.IgnoreElements())
    .Select(_ => Unit.Default);
```

If the sequences are of different type, you could project each one of them to an `IObservable<Unit>` before merging, or use the `CombineLatest` instead of the `Merge`. Lots of options.

Comment: Thank you! Why do we need `LastOrDefaultAsync()` though?

Comment: @jackdry good question! We don't need it, so I'll remove it from the answer. The `LastOrDefaultAsync` is needed if you want to `Wait` or `await` the sequence, because awaiting empty sequences results to an exception.